# Ionic2 two ion-datetime next to each other

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

So, I've got page which contains an ion-content and this contains a ion-list.

An ion-list contains ion-items. This is a container for elements like an input, label, etc.

I made a (very ugly) image which represent what I want to accomplish.

[image: What i want]

> This is code that works to get the 2 labels next to each other like the picture above (blue sections).

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Label 1</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Label 2</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

> Now I want to get 2 ion-datetime elements next to each other, so I tried this.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-datetime></ion-datetime>
    <ion-datetime></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

This is the result.

[image: Result]

For this example there is no code to provide data to show in the ion-datetime elements, but in my project there is.

Does anyone know how i can get this to work?

> Below is an example how to get it working. We figured it's a bug so I reported it here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9818.

Comment: What about css `display: inline-block`?

Comment: I've got the answer I was looking for. 
Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ion-row` and `ion-col` elements to achieve that layout (or something similar at least):

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Label 1</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Label 2</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="startDate"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="endDate"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-list>
```

Although I'm not sure if this is a valid option in the context of your app.

Comment: This works, but I'm working with a startdate and an enddate, so the ngModel will be bound to 2 diferent properties.

Comment: Oh, that was just to create the demo faster :) I've updated the answer. The main idea is that you can create complex layouts by using Ionic row and col elements.

Comment: Ok, this works! I was just trying this but without the ion-item in the ion-col.

Comment: It will work without the `ion-item` as well, it just adds some padding, borders and some other things related to styling the elements.

Comment: I've just tried that and it does not work. When you click on the left side you'll adjust the right datetime editor. But you won't be able to adjust the left datetime editor.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Seems like a bug... So the `ion-item` should be used to wrap the `ion-datetime` to make it work properly.